# Need an Excel formula to look for first occurrence in array

Tags: excel-formula

I'm looking for an excel formula that goes in each row of column P that finds which number shows up first (between columns M and N) in the unsorted array (A through K). I have pasted the results I'm looking for in column P....For example, in Row 2 the formula should look for whether 54.3% or 0% shows up first in the array from A2 to K2...the answer is 54.3%

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typically, we don't answer questions where the original question shows zero effort, but here is a formula that will work.

```
=OFFSET(A2,0,MIN(MATCH(E2,$A2:$C2,0),MATCH(F2,$A2:$C2,0))-1)
```

[image]

Adjusted for your data set the formula is this:

```
=OFFSET(A2,0,MIN(MATCH(M2,$A2:$K2,0),MATCH(N2,$A2:$K2,0))-1)
```

Comment: Scott - appreciate the response. I've been trying MATCH and INDEX without any luck so I'm thinking I've been way off...in anycase I tried your formula "=OFFSET(A2,0,MIN(MATCH(M2,$A2:$K2,0),MATCH(N2,$A2:$K2,0))-1)"  but get an error as a result...

Comment: Scott - I found my error...no issues. Thanks this worked

Comment: glad it worked. it's helpful to those moving forward if you make an answer as the correct one. I encourage to mark this answer or the other provided as correct.

Answer (score 0):

AGGREGATE will perform array like operations with certain formula choices.  In this example I will be using choice 15 which is just one of those aforementioned choices.  Because it performs array operations avoid using full column/row references within the array.

Based on your date being layed out as per the image below, place the following formula in P2 and copy down.

[image: POC]